# Usare 'è' alla fine di una frase

Tags: verbs

Si può usare 'è' alla fine di questa frase:

> La questione dei 'Quota 96' è emblematica del caos in cui l'Italia è.

?

O, anteponendo 'è' a 'l'Italia', sarebbe meno cacofonico dire:

> La questione dei 'Quota 96' è emblematica del caos in cui è l'Italia.

?

Oppure fra le due costruzioni c'è una differenza di enfasi?

So che si potrebbe usare 'versa' o 'si trova', ma nel contesto del discorso vorrei comunque usare 'è'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammaticalmente entrambe le frasi sono ineccepibili; farei però queste osservazioni:

- La parola in fondo alla frase, in cui la frase si risolve, qui è la più rilevante. Il caos in cui  l'Italia *è*: cioè,  in cui  concretamente e stabilmente si trova.
  Il caos in cui è *l'Italia*: cioè, non quello in cui sono il Portogallo o la Finlandia.
- L'aspetto fonologico non mi pare rilevante: lo iato non produce necessariamente un effetto sgradevole da evitare, e qui casomai dà un maggiore risalto  al verbo. In ogni caso no, non mi pare che la seconda versione sia più cacofonica.
- La scelta del verbo: si possono scegliere altri verbi o costruzioni per rendere l'idea  di una condizione di caos più o meno transitoria e più o meno casuale: per es. *in cui l'Italia si trova/è venuta a trovarsi/è capitata*. Il verbo essere mi pare la scelta più semplice e più la più forte e pregnante  (e la più veritiera, oimé: si parla del caos in cui l'Italia *è*, più o meno dalle origini, non dello stato di alta pressione meteorologica in cui *si trova* dall'inizio della settimana).
- In riferimento al titolo: "usare 'è' alla fine di una frase" non è poi così inusuale, specialmente se fa parte di una proposizione relativa corta, come nelle frasi riportate nella domanda (bisogna fare il fuoco con la legna che c'è; è quello che è, lasciare tutto come è; e io so dove è…)

Personalmente avrei scritto la prima frase.

Answer (score 4):

Le due costruzioni proposte sono entrambe valide. Come osservi, però, lasciare la vocale accentata da sola a fine frase non è molto comodo da pronunciare (ed è anche un po' strano da leggere). Per cui, se vuoi utilizzare il vocabolo "è", io sceglierei la seconda versione.

Io personalmente non sento alcuna differenza di enfasi tra le due frasi.

Answer (score 3):

Secondo me non suona bene la prima versione con "è" in fondo alla frase, sembra un errore o una frase non terminata. Mi aspetterei alla fine, se dovessi leggere questa frase, un:

> ... in cui l'Italia è caduta, o finita.

Cioè una frase con un passato prossimo e non un tempo presente.

Answer (score 3):

Porre "è" in fondo alla frase, pur essendo grammaticalmente corretto e comprensibile, rende molto più difficile interpretare la frase: è estremamente insolito vedere una tale struttura. La continuazione "naturale" sarebbe un participio passato, per formare un tempo composto - "in cui l'Italia è caduta", per dire - e invece si trova un punto, che costringe l'interlocutore ad analizzare nuovamente la frase, interrompendo il *flow*.

Questo genere di frase è detto **garden path sentence**. Un esempio classico che aiuta a comprenderlo, se sai l'inglese, è "the old man the boat": il lettore interpreta la frase nel modo standard, giunge a una frase incoerente (the man who is old; the boat), e deve interpretare nuovamente il testo per comprenderlo (the boat is manned by old people). Lo stesso avviene ponendo "è" in fondo alla frase; sostituiscilo con un verbo più specifico e non ausiliare.